# mysqli-- prepare statement failing with error "no table used"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepare

new to writing in php, I'm using a $mysqli->prepare() function to get a statement ready for execution, but it keeps failing and I don't know why. THe error inside the $mysqli->error is "no table used," and I can't seem to find much documentation for that either... if anyone could help out, that would be hugely appreciated. Code below:

```
$datasqli=new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE); // defined elsewhere
if ($datasqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $datasqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ($usertest = $datasqli->prepare("INSERT INTO eeg (Identifier) 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT ? ) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Identifier FROM eeg WHERE Identifier = ?
    ) LIMIT 1")) {
    // this stuff never gets executed...
} else {
    echo $datasqli->error; // "no table used"
}
```

I've tried executing that code block directly inside the mysql environment and it works fine.

Comment: Why do you think it's prepared statement problem at all? Dud you try your query in console?

Comment: Sorry--yes I did try it in the console, and it executed fine, which is why I am a bif confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently,

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ? )
```

...is not recognized as a valid MySQL syntax. A table name is missing.

***EDIT**, Concerning your comments:*

First of all, please note that executing this statement in a console by substituting `?` with a constant does not emulate your situation, so I would consider the result invalid for comparison.

But then again, executing it *without* substituting `?` would, naturally, give an error.

That's because executing just the select is irrelevant to your situation. In your php code, it's not the *execution* that fails but rather the *preparation*. So the proper way to emulate this using a console, would be the [`PREPARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html) statement.

So doing a

```
PREPARE myStmt 
  FROM 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT ? ) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Identifier FROM eeg WHERE Identifier = ?
    ) LIMIT 1'
```

would reproduce your issue more accurately.

Now, it seems that `PREPARE` has a difficulty understanding parametrized nested queries *that appear in the `FROM` clause*. Take a look at these examples:

```
PREPARE myStmt FROM "select * from (select ? from eeg) tmp";
```

*(doesn't work)*

```
PREPARE myStmt FROM "select *,? from (select * from eeg) tmp";
```

*(works)*

```
PREPARE myStmt FROM "select *,? from (select 'asdf') tmp";
```

*(works)*

```
PREPARE myStmt FROM "select * from eeg where Identifier in (select ?)";
```

*(works)*

Curious behaviour, but I can only guess that *when a nested `SELECT` in the `FROM` clause has parameters, MySQL is missing clues in order to prepare the statement*.

As for my suggestion, if I understand what you are trying to do, you don't need a parameter in the nested select. You could move it outside and hardcode a constant in the nested select, for the sake of `FROM`. The following code

```
if ($usertest = $datasqli->prepare("INSERT INTO eeg (Identifier) 
    SELECT ? from (select 1) tmp WHERE ? NOT IN
      (SELECT Identifier FROM eeg WHERE Identifier = ?)")) {
```

...should do the trick.

Comment: That's curious--if I try the query in console, substituting the ? for a string, it goes through without complaint. Can you suggest another way of phrasing this query?

Comment: Well, that would depend on the possible values to substitute `?`. What are you using in your tests?

Comment: A string that corresponds to an "Identifier" value--in the test, 'asdf' but that's less relevant. It's a nice little bif of SQL I found on here to insert values into a table only if certain non-primary keys didn't exist, though I confess,`SELECT * FROM (SELECT ?) AS tmp` I don't entirely understand

Comment: Ooops, I missed the part about what I'd suggest. Please see _updated_ edit.

Comment: Thank you! And even more so for the explanation than the fix

Comment: You cannot use placeholders for table and column names, as shown in the duplicate. MySQL recognizes nested prepared queries just fine if you set it up correctly. Your `SELECT ?` will fail as you're trying to use a placeholder for a column name. Same for `WHERE ?` In other words, your code will not *"do the trick"*.